# How to deploy jar artifacts directly from a maven repository to appserver specific directories

Tags: maven-2

I have JDBC driver dependencies (e.g. h2, mysql ..) which have to be copied under ${jboss.home}/common/lib before it is used by my EAR application. What would be the best way to directly copy from a maven repository into the above location instead of doing a manual copy. I would not prefer to store copies of the drivers as part of my SVN.

Note: I currently specify this as a maven dependency and copy this artifact from the local repository, not sure if this is the best way to do solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its [`dependency:copy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) goal that allows to *copy a list of artifacts from the repository to defined locations*. See the [Copying specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) example.